# How to make node require es5 lib from node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, binary, ecmascript-5

I am trying to convert Express.js project to binary, and I am using zeit/pkg libary. However, it gave me an error every time I try to use pkg.

[image]

Is there a way that I can force Node/Npm to use es5 instead of es6.

Comment: Might help to use a newer node.js version. Have a look here https://node.green/

Answer (score 0):

in your snapshot the module is being imported from  `..er/node_modules/safefs/es6/lib/safefs.js`

notice it is importing from `es6` which has `export` keyword. that means its an es6 module and your node supports 'commonjs' require.
which is why this require may be failing.

you can download latest version of `node` where you can resolve es6 modules.